# What does it mean to say "what was it about me?"

Tags: meaning

It's part of a business letter:

That’s kinda in my mind, like, “man, what was it about me--” and I’m fine with it now, it is what it is. When I was younger, I used to wonder about that a lot. Like, “golly, what was it about me that a person could think that--”

Just like, “what is it about me that would allow someone to even entertain the possibility that I could do this?” Is that the thing?

Comment: Which bit is part of the business letter? Seems very informal.

Comment: This kind of informality is appropriate only in conversation; that it could be part of a business letter is very odd in terms of "register," a concept that seems confusing the many learners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means, what quality of mine caused a person to think that about me.
An example:

B: A is unbearable

A (to C): What is it about me that would cause B to think that?

C: Maybe It's you're annoying high-pitched voice

here, A is asking C which quality of A would cause B to make such a statement

EDIT: In your example, the subject is asking himself rather than talking to a 3rd person